# "sort filename | uniq" does not work on large files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, command-line-interface

I can remove duplicate entries from small text files, but not large text files.
I have a file that's 4MB.
The beginning of the file looks like this:

```
aa
aah
aahed
aahed
aahing
aahing
aahs
aahs
aal
aalii
aalii
aaliis
aaliis
...
```

I want to remove the duplicates.
For example, "aahed" shows up twice, and I would only like it to show up once.

No matter what one-liner I've tried, the big list will not change.

If It type:
**sort big_list.txt | uniq | less**
I see:

```
aa
aah
aahed
aahed   <-- didn't get rid of it
aahing
aahing   <-- didn't get rid of it
aahs
aahs   <-- didn't get rid of it
aal
...
```

However, If I copy a small chunk of words from the top of this text file and re-run the command on the small chunk of data, it does what's expected.

Are these programs refusing to sort because the file is too big?  I didn't think 4MB was very big. It doesn't output a warning or anything.

I quickly wrote my own "uniq" program, and it has the same behavior.  It works on a small subset of the list, but doesn't do anything to the 4MB text file.  What's my issue?

**EDIT:**
Here is a hex dump:

```
00000000  61 61 0a 61 61 68 0a 61  61 68 65 64 0a 61 61 68  |aa.aah.aahed.aah|
00000010  65 64 0d 0a 61 61 68 69  6e 67 0a 61 61 68 69 6e  |ed..aahing.aahin|
00000020  67 0d 0a 61 61 68 73 0a  61 61 68 73 0d 0a 61 61  |g..aahs.aahs..aa|
00000030  6c 0a 61 61 6c 69 69 0a  61 61 6c 69 69 0d 0a 61  |l.aalii.aalii..a|
00000040  61 6c 69 69 73 0a 61 61  6c 69 69 73 0d 0a 61 61  |aliis.aaliis..aa|
```

---

```
61 61 68 65 64 0a
a  a  h  e  d  \r

61 61 68 65 64 0d
a  a  h  e  d  \n
```

**Solved: Different line delimiters**

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any trailing whitespace or other invisible characters on some of those lines?  `uniq` shouldn't care how large the file is, since (due to its requirement that the file already be sorted) it only needs to store a couple of lines in memory at a time.

Comment: Is it possible the lines differ in a way that it's not obvious? For example in white space or line separator char

Comment: Nothing obvious, but I suppose that may be the case. However, when I paste a bit of it into a different file and do it again it works.  wouldn't I have pasted those characters too? Maybe you're right though, and it's some strange invisible ASCII character that my clipboard doesn't pickup........

Comment: Perhaps lines differ in trailing spaces?

Comment: maybe you can use `head` command to test if it works on the first few lines only?

Comment: @Xploit could you write it up as an answer and accept that? This will help others in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can normalize line delimeters (convert CR+LF to LF):

```
sed 's/\r//' big_list.txt | sort -u
```

Answer (score 6):

The [sort(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sort.htm) command accepts a `-u` option for uniqueness of key.

Just use

```
 sort -u big_list.txt
```

Comment: should work yes, but I still see duplicates when I pipe that into "less".  BUT, If I take that chunk I see from the output of "less", paste it into a different file, and run the same commands on that file, it removes the duplicates.

Comment: Pipe it into a file and use a hexeditor for comparing the allegedly duplicated lines.

Comment: @skai in hex, 0a 0d where the different line delimiters.. *sigh*,  thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To answer [max taldykin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147057/)'s question about `awk '!_[$0]++' file`:

`awk '!_[$0]++' file` is the same as

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
```

, which is the same as

```
awk '!seen[$0]++ { print; }' file
```

, which means

```
awk '
    {
        if (!seen[$0]) {
            print;
        }
        seen[$0]++;
    }' file
```

Important points here:

1. `$0` means the current *record* which usually is the current line
2. In `awk`, the *ACTION* part is optional and the default action is `{ print; }`
3. In *arithmetic* context, an uninitialized var is `0`

Comment: This trick is often used in scripting languages which support *hash* or *associative arrays*. Here is [an example with Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20can%20I%20extract%20just%20the%20unique%20elements%20of%20an%20array%3F).

Answer (score 2):

apart from `sort -u`  you can also use `awk '!_[$0]++' yourfile`

Comment: @clarkw, thanks but this does not help to understand what `!_[$0]++` means